# Excel VBA: Pass `Target` Variable from Click Event to Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am building an Excel 2016 Userform using VBA and need to collect the row and column of the cell from which the form is opened. I open the form on a cell double click with `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` and then initialize the Userform with `UserForm_Initialize()`. I would like to pass the `Target` of the double click event to `UserForm_Initialize()` but am not sure how to. [This forum thread](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/127789-pass-target-variable-from-worksheet-change-event-to-userform-textbox) addresses this issue, but the provided solutions did not work for me.

Here is my `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Column = Target.Column
    Row = Target.Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column B(2)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlDown).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 2
    lCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(lRow, lCol))) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        EdgeEntryForm.Show
    End If

End Sub
```

And my `UserForm_Initialize()`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Column As Long, Row As Long 'I would like to fill these with the Target values
    MsgBox ("Row is " & Row & " Column is " & Column)
     'Description.Caption = "Fill out this form to define a network edge from " & Cells(2, Row).Value & " to " & Cells(Column, 2).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: You could make use of the `ActiveCell`, given you are double clicking... no need to pass the target through. Something like: `MsgBox ("Row is " & ActiveCell.Row & " Column is " & ActiveCell.Column)`

Comment: @FAB That is what I had previously implemented, but I received feedback that `ActiveCell` should be avoided because it can cause bugs if a user clicks another cell while the form is open.

Comment: That's true, but you can just assign it to a variable, `Dim rngActCell as range: Set rngActCell = ActiveCell` , this should happen instantly as you open the userform... so whatever the user clicks afterwards, shouldn't matter.

Comment: Oh sweet. Thank you very much. Feel free to submit your code as an answer.

Comment: @FAB +1 for the variable usage. Most devs I know do use this enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in my comments, one way would be to just use the `ActiveCell` and assign that to a variable.

Alternatively, if you do want to pass it as a variable, you can do it with a bit of a workaround, by having a global variable to temporarly hold that information:

In your **worksheet** code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'.....
    With UserForm1
        Set .rngTarget = Target
        .Show
    End With
'.....
End Sub
```

In your **userform**:

```vb
Public rngTarget As Range
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
'....
    If Not rngTarget Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Row is " & rngTarget.Row & " Column is " & rngTarget.Column)
    Else
        MsgBox "something went wrong with assigning rngTarget variable"
    End If
'....
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** I was trying initially to propose something similar to @MathieuGuindon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528444/6373435), but was failing due to my limited knowledge on the difference between initialise and activate (thanks Mathieu).

I've updated the answer to make use of the global variable at userform level, rather than use one from a module.

Comment: Moving the field/variable into the form's code-behind is a must! Upvoted =)

Answer (score 2):

The form is shown modally, so `ActiveCell` isn't going to change on you, and should be safe to use in the form's code-behind.

The problem with that, is that you've now tied the form to `ActiveSheet`/`ActiveCell`, and now in order to test anything you need to `Select` or `Activate` a cell.

If the form code only needs to know about the cell's `Address`, then it shouldn't be given a `Range` (give it a `Range` and it can access any cell in any sheet in any workbook in the `Application` instance) - that's the *principle of least knowledge* at play. But this is obviously example code, so let's go with a `Range`:

```
Option Explicit
Private internalWorkingCell As Range

Public Property Get WorkingCell() As Range
    Set WorkingCell = internalWorkingCell
End Property

Public Property Set WorkingCell(ByVal value As Range)
    Set internalWorkingCell = value
End Property
```

Now your form code can use `WorkingCell` or `internalWorkingCell` to do its thing, and **no global variable** needs to float around;

```
With New UserForm1 ' Initialize handler runs here
    Set .WorkingCell = Target 
    .Show ' Activate handler runs here
End With
```

The `WorkingCell` *belongs* to the form - it has no business being in global scope.

Careful with the `Initialize` handler in forms - *especially* when you use its *default instance* (i.e. when you don't `New` it up): you don't control when that handler runs, the VBA runtime does; `UserForm_Initialize` will run the first time the form instance is *referenced* (in your case, immediately before the `.Show` call), and then never again unless the instance is destroyed (clicking the red X button would do that).

A `MsgBox` call in the `Initialize` handler will run *before* the form is shown; you probably want to move that code to the `Activate` handler before it causes problems.

Comment: I like your solution... I`ll definitely keep this in mind for future use. in his case using the double click event kind of implies having to activate a sheet/cell.

Comment: @FAB the form itself shouldn't care or assume what it's being shown from. A well-design form (or any module really) stands on its own, and has its *dependencies* passed from the outside - as opposed to *reaching out and getting them where they are*.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu, I'm learning something every day by trying to help others, and this is one of those moments. I've used a bit of inspiration from your answer to edit my answer, but if that's a problem, please let me know and I'll be happy to revert it back to what it was.

Comment: @FAB no problem whatsoever! All that matters is that the page contains correct information when dozens of people land here from Google searches =)